# Uploading image from Android to server - only portion of image uploaded

Tags: php, android, image

My application requires to upload multiple images to the server. I am sending the image by decoding Base64.

```
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

And in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP),

```
       $path = "/".$filename.".jpeg";
       $buffer = base64_decode($base);
       $handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
       $numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
       fclose($handle);
       ob_clean();
       flush();
```

Now I can see, some images are only uploaded partially. I can see only the uppermost few bits of the image and all blank in the server. What might be wrong? Are there any drawbacks in using Base64 decoding?

Answer (score 0):

try [checksum](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/checksum) for the file to make sure that file is uploaded completely

you can check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-a-file-checksum-value-in-java/) for generating checksum of a file in android

Answer (score -1):

please use this method.i hope its useful to you.In your code,may be image pixel is show so high.then you can't see image in server.

```
/**
     * encodes image to string using Base64
     * 
     * @return String imageString
     */
    **

private String prepareImage() {
        if (tempPath == null || (!isProfilechanged)) {
            return "";
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, options);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = com.qwiches.utils.Base64.encodeBytes(byteArray);
        bitmap = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return imageString;
    }
```

**

Comment: Note that if you require high-quality images, this method won't work well for you as it scales the image down to a 50x50px image.

Comment: yes.because when image size is too high then no to upload server without scale.

Comment: If the OP doesn't care about resolution, then your solution works fine. If he does care about it, yours won't work. That was my only point.

Comment: @dipali, What difference does it make on compressing your way and my way ? I mean, does it come over the problem of "not uploading whole file" ? or is it just to minimise the size ?? Can you suggest any idea to check if the image is completely uploaded in the server ?

Comment: @NathanWalters, I won't need very good pixels. So, if it solves the  issue, this solution is fine. But if its only to reduce the size, I dont think it is the solution. Can you suggest any idea to check if the image is completely uploaded in the server ?